# Ignore propriedade ICollection AutoMapper não funciona

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Pessoal estou com problema para ignorar uma propriedade que está como ICollection e outra que está como Class genérica.
Tipo estou ignorando no Profile Map classe Address, ele funciona somente quando Mapea PersonAddressEditViewModel> Person, quando mapea Person  > PersonAddressEditViewModel não funciona.

Estou utilizando a versão do AutoMapper 8.0. Já testei a versão 6.2.2 e continua o mesmo problema.

```
public class Person
        {
            public Person ()
            {
                Gid = Guid.NewGuid ();
                Address = new List <Address> ();
                ClientTypePersonDetails = new List <ClientTypePersonDetail> ();
            }
            [Key]
            public Guid Gid {get; set; }
            public string Email {get; set; }
            public string Name {get; set; }
            public DateTime Created_At {get; set; }
            public DateTime? Updated_At {get; set; }
            
           
            public bool IsDeleted {get; set; }

            // [NotMapped, IgnoreMap]
            public ValidationResult ValidationResult {get; set; }
           public virtual ICollection <Address> Address {get; set; }


        public class PersonAddressEditViewModel
        {
            public PersonAddressEditViewModel ()
            {
                Gid = Guid.NewGuid ();
                ClientTypePersonDetails = new List <ClientTypePersonDetailEditViewModel> ();

            }

            [Display (Name = "ID")]
            public Guid Gid {get; set; }

            [Display (Name = "Customer type person")]
            public string ClientTypeGid {get; set; }
             
            [NotMapped, IgnoreMap]
            public ValidationResult ValidationResult {get; set; }

            public virtual AddressEditViewModel Address {get; set; }


public class PersonProfile: Profile
        {
            public PersonProfile ()
            {
                CreateMap <PersonEditViewModel, Person> (). ReverseMap ();
                CreateMap <PersonEditViewModel, Address> (). ReverseMap ();
                CreateMap <PersonEditViewModel, PersonAddressEditViewModel> (). ReverseMap ();
                CreateMap <PersonAddressEditViewModel, Address> (). ReverseMap ();
              CreateMap <PersonAddressEditViewModel, Person> ()
                   .ForMember (x => x.Address, x => x.Ignore ()). ReverseMap ();
                CreateMap <PersonEditViewModel, PersonSearchViewModel> (). ReverseMap ();
                CreateMap <PersonEditViewModel, PersonIndexViewModel> (). ReverseMap ();
                CreateMap <PersonSearchViewModel, PersonIndexViewModel> (). ReverseMap ();
            }
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]